# Boost.MultiArray arbitrary start and end index

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class that looks like this. The purpose is to have an arbitrary starting and ending point, but operator [] maps to index 0 for the lower bound.

```
template <class T>
class Vec : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    Vec()
    {
        this->reserve(32000);
    }

    Vec(std::string s, int upperbound, int lowerbound)
    {
        SetBounds(s, upperbound, lowerbound);
    }

    void SetBounds(const std::string& s, int upperbound, int lowerbound)
    {
        mys = s;
        ub = upperbound;
        lb = lowerbound;

        std::cout << "resizing Vec for symbol: "
                  << symbol     << " "
                  << upperbound << " "
                  << lowerbound << " "
                  << upperbound - lowerbound << '\n';


        try
        {
           this->resize(ub - lb + 1);
        }
        catch(std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << "Resize Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "SetBounds exception" << "\n";
        }
    }
public:
    T& operator[] (int idx)
    {
        try
        {
            //std::cout << idx << std::endl;

            return this->at(idx - lb);
        }
        catch(std::exception& ex)
        {
           std::cout << "Access Exception: " << idx << " " << symbol << " " << ex.what() << '\n';
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "Access Exception: " << idx << " "  << symbol << '\n';
        }
    }

private:
    std::string mys;
    int ub;
    int lb;
};
```

My question is, is there an equivalent way to do this with Boost.MultiArray so that  each dimension can be given its own arbitrary starting and end index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_base

> #### Setting The Array Base
>
> In some situations, it may be inconvenient or awkward to use an array that is zero-based. the Boost.MultiArray components provide two facilities for changing the bases of an array. One may specify a pair of range values, with the extent_range type, to the extent_gen constructor in order to set the base value.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
> typedef boost::multi_array_types::extent_range range;
> // OR typedef array_type::extent_range range;
>
> array_type::extent_gen extents;
>
> // dimension 0: 0-based
> // dimension 1: 1-based
> // dimension 2: -1 - based
> array_type A(extents[2][range(1,4)][range(-1,3)]);
> ```
>
> An alternative is to first construct the array normally then reset the bases. To set all bases to the same value, use the reindex member function, passing it a single new index value.

Comment: Internally, is that implemented as pointer arithmetic for speed?

Comment: It's just implemented as arithmetic. Not for speed. But for implementation (how else would it work). They _did_ take great care to make index calculations optimizable by the compiler, if that's what you mean. This is very relevant on Intel CPUs because of the various indexed addressing modes that can make a huge difference over "manual" calculations